# TypeScript complaining about a proper HTML5 Fullscreen API method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html5-video

this.video.exitFullscreen();

I get this error:

[ts] Property 'exitFullscreen' does not exist on 
type 'HTMLVideoElement'

This method does exist and my reference to the video is 100% right because I have used it many times in my code. How do I solve this so typescript will compile without giving me this error?

I found one answer which suggests to implement an interface like this:

```
interface Document {
    exitFullscreen: () => void;
    mozCancelFullScreen: () => void;
    webkitExitFullscreen: () => void;
    fullscreenElement: () => void;
    mozFullScreenElement: () => void;
    webkitFullscreenElement: () => void;
}
```

but how can I use this interface if I already have two interfaces defined (for state and props) and my class is already using them:

```
class Player extends React.Component<IProps, IState> { ... }
```

I can't use the third interface on this class. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you're looking for [document.exitFullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitFullscreen), as `HTMLVideoElement.exitFullscreen` does not exist according to MDN.

Can you try `document.exitFullscreen()`? Rather than calling `exitFullscreen` on `this.video`.

As you pointed out, typescript doesn't know about the moz prefixed functions, so adding this file anywhere in your project (you don't have to derive from it) should remove your compiler errors for `document.mozCancelFullScreen`

```
interface Document {
    mozCancelFullScreen: () => void;
    mozFullScreenElement: Element;
}
```

Comment: I managed this to partially work on document without implementing that interface but I can only use .exitFullscreen() and .webkiteExitFullscreen() methods. mozCancelFullScreen() and others do not work (when using typescript).

Comment: Yes it seems that `exitFullscreen` is not fully implemented by browsers yet, so I'd be careful about using it in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type assertion to give the compiler a hint:

```
(this.video as Document).exitFullscreen();
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution a bit better?

Comment: You'd be giving the compiler a completely incorrect hint, `this.video` is a `HTMLVideoElement` - casting it to a `Document` isn't going to change that as the types are not compatible at all. This seems like a very lazy "make the error go away with as little effort as possible" solution, which doesn't actually fix the issue. The compiler won't complain, but `exitFullscreen` still doesn't exist on that object.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. It is a sketchy "please compile so I can get something done today" hack around the typings enforcement, and would only probably work in the file that included the `Document` interface contained in the question, since it adds the props that would more correctly come from `HTMLVideoElement`.